# Necessary informations about the practice of kumbhaka in pranayama?

Tags: pranayama

What is kumbhaka in pranayama and can it be practiced by anyone having subtle and gross sense enjoyments and non-brahmachari?

Comment: No. Kumbhaka is a more serious practice. You might need to see a guru first to check if you are fit for it. Otherwise you would run into a lot of trouble.